# Trimming a directory path String

Tags: java

I have a String file path

```
String filePath = "/tmp/test/save/data/java/"
```

and would like to remove the last 2 directories and last `/` so that,

```
String filePath = "/tmp/test/save"
```

I don't want to create a substring removing the last 10 characters, as the directories might change in length.
I was thinking about doing a combination of `split` (setting a limit and removing the final index), then `join` to recreate the string with `/` seperators, but wondering if there's a cleaner way ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [`java.nio.file.Path#getParent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#getParent--).

```java
String result = Paths.get("/tmp/test/save/data/java/").getParent()
                  .getParent().toString();
```

Answer (score 3):

From `java.nio.file.Path` we can use `subpath`:

```
Path path = Path.of("/tmp/test/save/data/java/");
String result = "/" + path.subpath(0, path.getNameCount() - 2);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use a combination of `lastIndexOf("/")` and `subString()` in a for loop to remove the unwanted directories.
[Java String documentations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) to learn how to use the methods.

Comment: This is not platform safe